# Correct statistical method to compare rating scales

Tags: r, anova

During a perceptual experiment participants were asked to adjust the parameters of a sound synthesis model in order to match a sound they had in mind.
After the experiment, a perceptual questionnaire was provided consisting of 4 items to be evaluated on a visual analog scale (VAS):

1) To what extent did you change the parameters of the sound in order to match mental representation A?

2) To what extent did you change the parameters of the sound in order to match mental representation B?

3) To what extent did you change the parameters of the sound in order to match mental representation C?

4) To what extent did you change the parameters of the sound in order to match mental representation D?

I need to assess whether there are significant differences between the use of the mental representations, e.g. if participants focused more to one rather than to another.
I analyzed this data with a one way repeated measure ANOVA where the answers of participants along all scales where the dependent variable and the 4 scales were the factor.
During the review process of the paper reporting the experiment results, I have been told by a reviewer that this is not the correct way to analyze the data since the 4 rating scales should be considered as the dependent variable instead. It is not clear to me what should be the factor then.

So I wonder, which is the correct way to analyze this data?
Maybe comparing somehow the confidence intervals?